# Is asking a duplicate question to an answered question OK, if it is phrased differently?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Just recently, I've asked a question on Stack Overflow. Before I made a 5 minute Internet and Stack Overflow check, I didn't find any answers.

A few minutes after posting the question, I found an answer on Stack Overflow. It was differently phrased, to such extent, that Google did not help me find it before.

I decided to mark my own question as duplicate, and accept it as such.
Should I instead delete it?

This is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700691/is-there-a-way-to-access-path-parameters-in-angular2-guard

I guess I should not delete it. But the bigger question is if I should deliberately ask duplicate questions, if I think that original question is not indexable enough (and flag it as duplicate ASAP).

Comment: You might want to read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841

Comment: @Stijn I wanted to put more emphasis on deliberately asking duplicate questions, but i guess it answers it more or less.

Comment: No, don't *deliberately* ask duplicate questions! But if you legitimately can't find the answer, and end up inadvertently asking a duplicate, then that's perfectly fine—as noted elsewhere, it serves as a pointer, making it easier to find the master question you couldn't.

Comment: _Before made 5m internet and SO check:_ In future, please invest more time into your research. This will also lower the chance that your question gets closed as duplicate...

Comment: To your edit: No!, you cal always edit a question and improve it. But don't reask the same question just to write it differently.

Comment: @CodyGray Thats the answer I've been looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @charlie_pl I've retracted my close vote, but the situation in your question wasn't deliberately asking a duplicate. You just found it quickly after posting your question.

Comment: This question is a meta-dupe.

Comment: @cp.engr Is asking duplicate question about a duplicate question ok, if it is phrased differently?